# carrierwave multiple uploader for single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have created a gallery module with the help of this tutorial https://kolosek.com/carrierwave-upload-multiple-images/ and now I want to add one more image attribute has a master image to the same model. So I thot of creating one more uploader but I'm bit confused about how to call that the controller can anybody help me out?

My code looks like this:

MOdel Code:

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :gallery 
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end

class Gallery < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :images
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end
```

gallery_controller.rb

```
 class GalleriesController < AdminController   
  def index
    @galleries = Gallery.all
  end

  def show
   @images = @gallery.images.all
  end

  def new
   @gallery = Gallery.new
   @image = @gallery.images.build
  end 

  def create
   @gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_params)
   respond_to do |format|
   if @gallery.save
     params[:images]['image'].each do |a|
      @images = @gallery.images.create!(:image => a, :gallery_id =>  @gallery.id)
    end
     format.html { redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully created.' }
     format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @gallery }
   else
     format.html { render :new }
     format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end

def gallery_params
  params.require(:gallery).permit(:title, :details, :status, images_attributes:[:id, :gallery_id, :image, :avatar])
end
```

Image Controller code:

```
class ImagesController < AdminController
 def image_params
   params.require(:image).permit(:gallery_id, :slideshow_id,:image, :avatar)
 end
end
```

form.html.erb

```
<%= form.fields_for :images do |p| %>
 <div class="field">
   <%= form.label :master_image, class: "col-2 col-form-label" %>
  <%= form.file_field :avatar, :multiple => true, name: "images[avatar][]" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= form.fields_for :images do |p| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :image, class: "col-2 col-form-label" %>
    <%= form.file_field :image, :multiple => true, name: "images[image][]" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I am confused in modifing the gallery controller create part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the images creation 2 times in the `create` method if you have 2 uploaders

```
params[:images]['image'].each do |a|
  @gallery.images.create!(:image => a, :gallery_id =>  @gallery.id)
end
params[:images]['avatar'].each do |a|
  @gallery.images.create!(:avatar => a, :gallery_id =>  @gallery.id)
end
```

but i think it's a little bit verbose and it not really prevents if you don't want to upload any image in your form (return `params[:images]['...']` nil)

Btw your form is not correct for the `form.fields_for`. It's :

```
<%= form.fields_for :images_attributes do |p| %>
 <div class="field">
   <%= p.label :master_image, class: "col-2 col-form-label" %>
   <%= p.file_field :avatar, :multiple => true, name: "images[avatar][]" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= form.fields_for :images_attributes do |p| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= p.label :image, class: "col-2 col-form-label" %>
    <%= p.file_field :image, :multiple => true, name: "images[image][]" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it solves the issue. But as u told this is a bit verbose what is the better method to do this?

Comment: But when the multiple images are uploaded and when I try to edit that the image upload option shows multiple times. what should I do?

Comment: @SushmaKv change the `fields_for` to : `<%= form.fields_for :images_attributes do |p| %>` (i edit my answer)

Comment: I want to add an option of uploading folder for the above. How can I do that?